# Padding issue in FireFox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

I use following style for sliding content in [your.edu.lk](http://your.edu.lk/), a website I am developing now.

```
width: 300px; 
height:70px; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-size: 40px; 
margin-top: 18px; 
padding-top:10px;
```

It is working fine in google chrome,But there is an issue in firefox. part of a sliding text can't see in firefox. you can check this by following above url. Still I can't figure it out a way to solve this issue. Is there any way to solve this issue.

My google chrome version - Version 29.0.1547.76 m and firefox version 24.0

Comment: This question has describe the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `height:70px;` try using `line-height:70px;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `line-height` property on Firefox. The current `line-height` is inherited from the parent `li` (`20px`). Setting this to a higher value will fix your problem.